# How to identify default_week_format in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, format, week-number

How can I identify the default_week_format in MySQL? I would like to know which default week format my server is using? Values can range between 0 and 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SHOW VARIABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-variables.html) command is what you're looking for.

Try with

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'default_week_format'
```